# library to play multiple sound files to different channels

Tags: library, audio, c++

I need to write c++ program to play different sound files into different output channels. Like playing multi language text to each different channel. I thought about [gigaporthd](http://www.esi-audio.com/products/gigaporthd+/)

Does anyone know how this device works?

Is there some library for Windows or Linux to play different sound to each channel?

Best Regards

Marek